# Share USB-storage between two devices

Tags: usb, file-transfer, usb-storage

This question will sound strange so bear with me and let me explain.

I have an embedded device, this device works in such a way that when a USB-storage is connected to it, it immediately creates a folder and dump lots of information in the folder.

My task is to verify that data and run some test on it. The actual tests are written in Python and run automatically, so the only problem is to somehow transfer the files from USB to my computer automatically

I am looking for a way to automate this process. I don't know if such a device exists, but the below diagram illustrates what I need.

```
PC <------ USB-STORAGE <-------EMBEDDED-DEVICE
```

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

(If possible, I also probably need to somehow emulate the actual inserting of the `USB-STORAGE` to the `EMBEDDED-DEVICE` since it will only then dump a new file)

Comment: Sounds like you need a [programmable USB switch](http://aluratek.com/2-port-usb-2-0-auto-sharing-switch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use a network drive for the USB storage, you can access the drive from your PC over the network.

so you get

PC --- *network* ---> USB Storage --- *plugged into* ---> Embedded device.

Cycling the power on the USB storage will cause it to be detected as inserted on the embedded device.